# What is the operation in mathematical do this order?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have long  rational equation.

How I can make one denominator by mathematical

[image]

```
\begin{eqnarray*}
f^{\prime \prime}(x)=\frac{4(3x^2+2x+1)}{(2x+1)(2x+1)^2}+\frac{2735 (547 + 5443200 x^5)}{(547 x + 907200 x^6)^2}-\frac{150 x}{1 + 70 x^2 + 600 x^4}+\frac{1000 x^3 (7 + 120 x^2)}{(1 + 70 x^2 + 600 x^4)^2}-\frac{1}{x}
\end{eqnarray*}
```

Comment: Well. I guess your question is off-topic here (and please make your matemathical homework by yourself, you should learn how to build a denominator, that's the sense behind the homework ... ;-)) If you have principal problems with that ask on a page handling mathematical questions like that ...

Answer (score 1):

I presume this question will be closed for being off topic, but I will give you an answer anyway. It would appear you are using Wolfram Mathematica so the command to find a common denominator is `Together[%]`. The result can then be exported to LaTeX by right-clicking and selecting Copy As > LaTeX. The output of which is this beautifully succinct expression:

```
\frac{1185137049600000000 x^{22}-1185137049600000000 x^{21}-829595934720000000 x^{20}-1343155322880000000 x^{19}-526398372864000000 x^{18}-186546737664000000 x^{17}+13595110502400000 x^{16}+53468858419200000 x^{15}+39572830402560000 x^{14}+19488870293760000 x^{13}+8001720761760000 x^{12}+2309729616288000 x^{11}+555834662640000 x^{10}+118403380195200 x^9+14187732200400 x^8+3019536490800 x^7+313383476640 x^6+67739429760 x^5+11287360316 x^4+1180678714 x^3+226800422 x^2+8677061 x+1496045}{x^2 (2 x+1)^3 \left(600 x^4+70 x^2+1\right)^2 \left(907200 x^5+547\right)^2}
```

Comment: thanxxx......................................